# How to edit variable from array instead of increments?

Tags: javascript

Follow this for full code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWRabY

Here is the part im having trouble with:

```
var dataID = 1;
$('svg rect.grid').each(function() {
$(this).attr('data-id', dataID);
dataID++
});
```

This dynamically creates an attribute 'data-id' to each 'svg rect.grid'(ie. a square) created starting from 1. The code generates 9 Squares.

I would like to change the dataID to use an array such as

```
 4, 9, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 1, 6
```

Instead of sequentially numbering each square 1-9.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an array and shift to get each element in turn:

```
var ids = [4, 9, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 1, 6];
$('svg rect.grid').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-id', ids.shift());
});
```

Note that this alters the array, so if you need to run this process multiple times, ensure that you are not storing the array somewhere permanently and that you re-initialize it each time.  (Putting this code inside of a function and calling it, for example, would work.)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I'm just getting my feet wet with Javascript and its still very confusing to me. Hopefully studying how this works will help me understand better!

Comment: @JamesBurton The array `.shift()` method is simple: it removes the first element (shifting all of the other elements down by one) and returns the element that it removed.